# How to return articles from followed users only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Right now i am successfully able to return every article without issue.
But what i want to do is this:
I want to return the articles,only followed by the current authenticated user. How can i do it?

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True,default='undefinedusername')
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class UserFollow(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='following')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='followers')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userfollowers_set = UserFollowSerializer(source='followers',required=False,many=True)
    userfollowing_set = UserFollowSerializer(source='following',required=False,many=True)
   
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','userfollowing_set','userfollowers_set')
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

Error 1:

```
    class FollowedAuthorFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
NameError: name 'filters' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author__following__author=request.user
        )
```

We can also move the filtering logic into a `FilterBackend`:

```
class FollowedAuthorFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            author__following__profile=request.user
        )
```

Then we can plug in this `FollowedAuthorFilterBackend` where we want to filter this, so we can rewrite our `ArticleViewSet` to:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    filter_backends = [FollowedAuthorFilterBackend]

    # no get_queryset
```

Comment: How can i use request.user ? I use django as an API for a mobile application, can i make a POST request to fill the request.user?

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: you will need to specify how to autenticate the user, for example with a JWT token: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/, or through some views where you make a POST request with credentials and retrieve a token.

Comment: Thanks a lot,i will try it and reply back as soon as possible (Tick the answer if its correct).

Comment: For further notice, i suggest `def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            author__following__profile=request.user
        )
` should be edited as 
`def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            author__following__author=request.user
        )`
because author is the followed,profile is following and it is user itself